# On my servlet url-pattern, the application works with "/path" but not with "/path/to"

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web

I have the following Java servlet:

```
package com.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Teste extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        request.setAttribute("teste", "Test");
        request.getSession().setAttribute("teste", "Test Session");
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("teste.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }

}
```

And the following `web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Teste</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.controller.Teste</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Teste</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/teste</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

I can access the servlet through the url `http://localhost:8084/myapp/teste`

What I want is change the url-pattern to `/teste/edit`, but when I do that, and try to access the servlet through the url `http://localhost:8084/myapp/teste/edit` I get the following 404 error:

> HTTP Status 404 - /TrabalhoPSW/teste/teste.jsp
>
> type Status report
>
> message /TrabalhoPSW/teste/teste.jsp
>
> description The requested resource is not available. Apache
>   Tomcat/8.0.27

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the JSP file that the servlet was trying to find. when I changed from

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("teste.jsp");
```

to

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/teste.jsp");
```

It worked normally.

Answer (score 0):

if you need than your servlet works with **/path** and **/path/to**, Change the mapping of servlet in web.xml to:

```
<url-pattern>/teste/*</url-pattern>
```